# iPhone and SOAP 1.2 (.net WCF)

Tags: iphone, soap, wsdl

I humbly ask your help in this subject for always receiving 0 bytes

These are the outputs I encountered:

```
TestWCFCalls[94830:f803] didReceiveResponse
2011-12-14 17:11:37.054 TestWCFCalls[94830:f803] connectionDidFinishLoading
2011-1214 17:11:37.055 TestWCFCalls[94830:f803] DONE. Received Bytes: 0
```

- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {

  ```
  //Variables used
  NSMutableData *webData;
  NSString *soapMessage = NSString stringWithFormat:

  @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
  "<soap12:Envelope \n"
  "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" \n"
  "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"  \n"
  "xmlns:soap12=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\"> \n"
  "<soap12:Body> \n"
  "<MobileLogOn xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"> \n"
  "<userID>test</userID><PWD>test</PWD></MobileLogOn> \n"
  "</soap12:Body> \n"
  "</soap12:Envelope>"];

  NSLog(soapMessage);

  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://10.10.10.75:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/MobileWCFService.WCFServices/UserLogOnServ/"];               
  NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];             
  NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];          
  [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];       
  [theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/iUserLogOnServ/MobileLogOn" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Soapaction"];
  [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
  [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];     
  [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

  if(theConnection) {
      NSLog(@"test");
      webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
  }
  else {
      NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
  }
  ```

}

-Web Configuration-

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="MobileWCFService.WCFServices.MobileUserLogOnServBehavior"
        name="MobileWCFService.WCFServices.MobileUserLogOnServ">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingName="MobileLogOnBinding"
          contract="MobileWCFService.WCFServices.IMobileUserLogOnServ">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://10.10.10.75:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/MobileWCFService.WCFServices/MobileUserLogOnServ/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
```

I'm not sure what part I missed but I'm pretty sure I missed some point, though I can call the service part but I haven't receive any data.

Kind Thanks,
Sel

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried with http://sudzc.com/ to create automatically your SOAP client?

Comment: I have tried sudzc.com but I can't generate, the site says like it can't connect to my local service file.

Comment: note that you can save the WSDL file to disk and load into SudzC website

Answer (score 0):

For consuming from iOS, the WCF binding should be BasicHttpBinding. In your case it's wsHttpBinding. That might be the reason.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply, but i need wsHttpBinding for wcf session part... I am running out of options with wcf session.


Is there any other way to implement iphone project with .net web service (SOAP 1.1, 1.2) that I can implement session?

Comment: I think only BasicHttpBinding can access from iPhone. I don't know any other methods.